# Basic authentication for 2 different handler

Tags: c#, basic-authentication, startup

I have an application that with consume `BasicAuthentication` to authenticate for endpoints, other than that I'm going to use `BasicAutheticationMetric` for metric to show some statistics. When I test the `BasicAuthenticationMetric` is going to `BasicAuthentication` and the test it fails.  Here is my code:

I have the startup class: `TestStartup.cs`

```
private static void AddAuth(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultScheme = AuthConstants.ApiPolicyScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = AuthConstants.ApiPolicyScheme;
    }).AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>
            (AuthConstants.ApiPolicyScheme, null);

    authBuilder.AddMetricsAuthentication();

    services.AddAuthorization(o =>
    {
        o.AddPolicy(AuthConstants.ApiPolicyName, new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AuthConstants.ApiPolicyScheme)
            .Build());

        o.AddPolicy(AuthConstants.MetricsPolicyName, new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AuthConstants.MetricsPolicyScheme)
            .Build());
    });
}


public static AuthenticationBuilder AddMetricsAuthentication(
     this AuthenticationBuilder authBuilder,
     string scheme = AuthConstants.MetricsPolicyScheme)
{
    authBuilder.AddScheme<
        MetricsLocalNetworkBasicAuthenticationOptions,
        MetricsLocalNetworkBasicAuthenticationHandler>(scheme, null);
    
    authBuilder.Services
        .AddOptions<MetricsLocalNetworkBasicAuthenticationOptions>(scheme)
        .Configure<IConfiguration>((options, config) =>
        {
            config.GetSection("MetricsAuthentication").Bind(options);
        });
        
        return authBuilder;
}
```

And the test method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task BasicAuthentication_WorksForMetrics()
{
    var client = await StartHost();
    
    SetBasicAuthMetric(client);
    
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/metrics");
    
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}

private static async Task<HttpClient> StartHost()
{
    var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
        {
            webHost.UseTestServer();
            webHost.UseStartup<TestStartup>();
        });
    
    var host = await hostBuilder.StartAsync();
        
    return host.GetTestClient();
}
```

When I debug it goes to `MetricsLocalNetworkBasicAuthenticationHandler` and after that it goes to `BasicAuthenticationHandler` and the test it fails. Do I need to add something else in the `TestStartup.cs`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this removing the default value in the startup.cs

```
var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(o).AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>
            (AuthConstants.ApiPolicyScheme, null);
```